# How do you get JQuery to wait until a previous event has fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a list of divs,whenever I click them I call a function,some trigger other ajax functions.
Now while the click even fires an ajax event,if I click another div I get last clicked div function called.How to solve this.

```
document.addEventListener("click",function(event){
                checkparent(event);

    } 

function checkpaternt(event){

    if(($(event.target).class=="checkparent"){//call ajax functions
    }
    else {//call local functions}
```

later I check the class name of the target and call different functions.
some more info(there are lots of div elements and if else statements)
Thank you.

Comment: disable other DIV click until ajax request is completed. You could use any boolean flag to check it

Comment: @A.Wolff how to disable a div

Comment: You can't, i was talking about filtering inside click handler of DIV depending any boolean flag. You have to set your logic like that instead

Comment: I mean wre to check the flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a boolean flag: (and fixing your code)

```
function checkparent(event) {
    if (ajaxRequestOn) return;
    if (event.target.className == "checkparent") {
        ajaxRequestOn = true;
        //call ajax functions
        $.ajax( /* ...*/ ).always(function () {
            ajaxRequestOn = false;
        });
    } else {
        //call local functions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think following example might help you.

```
callbacks = [$.Deferred(), $.Deferred()];
    obj1.on('click', callbacks[0].resolve);
    obj2.on('click', callbacks[1].resolve);

    $.when(callbacks).done(function() { console.log('After to events done'); });
```

Here I am creating two deferred object.

And each event resolving a deferred object.

when these all deferred object will be resolved next function you can write inside `.done()`

Comment: there are lots of divs so practically I cant write those many on click events.Thanks for the info though

Answer (score 0):

I think `element.type` will help you,

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="tipo-imovel" />
```

**Script**

```
$("#tipo-imovel").on("click change", function(event){
    alert(event.type + " is fired");
});
```

*This code will alert which event has been triggered*

I'd suggest you to look at [this possible events](http://help.dottoro.com/larrqqck.php)

Please let me know if it helped you

Comment: .live is deprecated, better use .on()

Comment: live is not only deprecated but has been removed from jQuery 1.9+

Comment: there are lots of divs so practically I cant write those many on click events.Thanks for the info though

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [jQuery queues](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue-queueName-callback-next-). Please go on below for the relevant quote:

**How can jQuery queues be used here**

*Working Example*

[This](http://learn.jquery.com/effects/uses-of-queue-and-dequeue/) is an amazing resource on using queues for custom ajax calls. I know the SO preference for archiving linked content, but I can't really copy code here, so I've also made a small fiddle showing custom queues - [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EuXW5/)

The example uses a text-color change, but that can easily be any AJAX call. The `setTimeout` has an asynch callback similar to many AJAX calls, this fiddle should be a useful template...

*Theory*

```
$('#elementId').click(function (e) {
  var $element = $(e.currenttarget);
  $element.queue('myqueue', function () {
    var $el = $(this);

    //Do stuff on $el

    //Remove this event from the queue and process next...
    $el.dequeue();
  });
});
```

Breaking this down:

1. Listen to the click event
2. Get the specific element clicked
3. Queue a function on the 'myqueue' of this element
4. The function to be queued may need a reference to this element - luckily jQuery calls it with the required element as the 'this' pointer.

If you desire a gap between two events, you could even put the dequeue inside a timeout like `window.setTimeout(500, function () { $this.dequeue(); });` , which sets a 500ms interval before the next event...

**jQuery Queue Docs**

> This feature is similar to providing a callback function with an
>   animation method, but does not require the callback to be given at the
>   time the animation is performed.

```
$( "#foo" ).slideUp(); $( "#foo" ).queue(function() {  
  alert( "Animation complete." );   
  $( this ).dequeue(); 
});
```

> This is equivalent to:

```
$( "#foo" ).slideUp(function() {   
  alert( "Animation complete."
); });
```

> Note that when adding a function with .queue(), we should
>   ensure that .dequeue() is eventually called so that the next function
>   in line executes.

*Update* The answer has been modified to include a working fiddle and some explanation as well.

Comment: How would you use it regarding events?